# SSH connection with key, not working with rsync

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync

After creating a key with no password, I can login with SSH to my remote host:

```
$ ssh root@machine.local
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.1...
```

However when I try to use SSH to rsync to the same remote host:

```
$ sudo rsync -avczr -e ssh /home root@machine.local:/destination
```

it asks for my root password on machine.local.

Why does SSH want to login with password for rsync, but with key if I connect directly? How do I make the rsync connection work with key?

One thing I noticed, which may be related, is that the first "authenticity of host can't be established" message I received mentioned the ECDSA key fingerprint, while the key I use for connecting directly are RSA.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out the problem was that I called `rsync` with `sudo` and was therefore running it as root. Therefore `ssh` called via `rsync` did not use my user's `~/.ssh/id*` files, but looked for `/root/.ssh/id_*` and found none.

I copied the  `~/.ssh/id*` files to `/root/.ssh/`, and now it works.